# problems displaying content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Clicking the response back to the other user in the private message system, a box will appear,

when I click on it so it will not be

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="svar" value="Svar" id="indholdcklik" class="click svarpm">
</form>
```

content to show up on the page

```
<div id="indholdbeksed">
hey
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#indholdbeksed {
    display: none;
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
.click {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #79bbff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 0%, #4197ee 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#79bbff), color-stop(100%,#4197ee));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 0%,#4197ee 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 0%,#4197ee 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #79bbff 0%,#4197ee 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #79bbff 0%,#4197ee 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#79bbff', endColorstr='#4197ee',GradientType=0 );
}
.click:hover {
    background: #4197ee;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4197ee 0%, #79bbff 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4197ee), color-stop(100%,#79bbff));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4197ee 0%,#79bbff 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #4197ee 0%,#79bbff 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #4197ee 0%,#79bbff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4197ee 0%,#79bbff 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4197ee', endColorstr='#79bbff',GradientType=0 );
}
```

and at the top of the page will be shown here:

**jQuery**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

$("#indholdcklik").click(function() {
  $("#indholdbeksed").slideDown("slow",function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: So what is the question? Question title says "problems", but you need to state clearly what the desired behaviour is, and what the actual behaviour is.

Comment: Unclear as to what you want

Comment: are you waiting for DOM ready handler? I mean, is click event fired?

Comment: "when I click on it so it will not be" uh.....

Comment: question / problem is about why #indholdbeksed not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/ew8uY/1/) and add `document.ready` to start your javascript then document is ready and add `return false` to prevent form submit.
Now all works fine.

Comment: It will still not appear on the page

Comment: Its work now!!. i need all jQuery to top. :D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your javascript code is between `<script>` tags and within

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

You should prevent the form from submitting. Pass the event to the callback function and stop the submit.

```
$("#indholdcklik").click(function(ev) { 
    ev.preventDefault();
    // everything else..
```

Comment: Its work now ;) so sorry :) ha a nice day :D